# ARCore in unity will let me RUN the game but not build and run

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, android-augmented-reality

*I am trying out ARCore(1.5.0) for unity (2019.1.0f2) and I am able to run the game on my phone by clicking the play button. But when I try to build and run it shows me multiple errors:*

> Library\PackageCache\com.unity.multiplayer-hlapi@1.0.4\Runtime\DefaultNetworkTransport.cs(73,37):
>   error CS0117: 'NetworkTransport' does not contain a definition for
>   'DoesEndPointUsePlatformProtocols'
>
> Library\PackageCache\com.unity.multiplayer-hlapi@1.0.4\Runtime\NetworkDiscovery.cs(317,30):
>   error CS0117: 'NetworkTransport' does not contain a definition for
>   'SetMulticastLock'
>
> Library\PackageCache\com.unity.multiplayer-hlapi@1.0.4\Runtime\NetworkDiscovery.cs(348,30):
>   error CS0117: 'NetworkTransport' does not contain a definition for
>   'SetMulticastLock'
>
> Library\PackageCache\com.unity.multiplayer-hlapi@1.0.4\Runtime\NetworkDiscovery.cs(388,30):
>   error CS0117: 'NetworkTransport' does not contain a definition for
>   'SetMulticastLock'
>
> Library\PackageCache\com.unity.multiplayer-hlapi@1.0.4\Runtime\NetworkDiscovery.cs(449,34):
>   error CS0117: 'NetworkTransport' does not contain a definition for
>   'SetMulticastLock'
>
> Library\PackageCache\com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.0\Scripts\Runtime\TMP_UpdateManager.cs(134,36):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ScriptableRenderContext'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)
>
> C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0f2\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.timeline\Runtime\Animation\AnimationOutputWeightProcessor.cs(21,9):
>   error CS0122: 'AnimationMotionXToDeltaPlayable' is inaccessible due to
>   its protection level
>
> C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0f2\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.timeline\Runtime\Events\Signals\SignalAsset.cs(11,6):
>   error CS0122: 'AssetFileNameExtensionAttribute' is inaccessible due to
>   its protection level
>
> Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors
>
> Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
>
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 9 errors
>
> at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer
>   (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194
>
> at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean
>   askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions)
>   [0x0007f] in
>   C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:97
>   UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

*These are all the errors I get when trying to build and run. I also have 31 warnings.*

Comment: Remove the Unity Multiplayer HLAPI in the package manager, if you are not using it.

Comment: Looks you have compile time errors in editor. Errors like this appears when Unity can't compile some assembly definition or something like this. Can you start unity and check console for logs / put it question?